# How to add new theme to Kate in KDE

Tags: kde, kate

I want to add "okyo night light" to my Kate editor in my kde.

I find "okyo night light" in this address "https://kate-editor.org/en-gb/themes/".

I can't find this theme in the Configure Kate window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.